# Simple way of clipping video files?

Tags: video

What is a simple way of extracting a video clip from, say, an .avi file? An example: I only want between 1:05 and 1:35 of this video, and I want to save the clip as its own file. I have been using Premiere Pro but it has not been particularly efficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VirtualDub](http://virtualdub.org) is probably the best tool for trimming/splitting **AVI** files (without recompression). For other formats, you should look for other tools, eg.:

- [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)
- [AVS Remaker](http://vegasaur.com/AVS-Video-Remaker)
- etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) to accomplish this. FFmpeg is a command line tool that is used to convert and cut audio and video.
 From [this](https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video) answer I got the sample code which I have rewritten for your purpose.

> ffmpeg -ss 00:01:05.0 -t 00:00:30.0 -i input.avi -acodec copy -vcodec copy -async 1 output.avi

Comment: Will this re-encode or not?

Comment: Does this work for .MOV ?